# Taylor Series Formulae

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How are the two following forms of the Taylor expansion equivalent?

The one I've learnt is $$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2!}f''(x)+...$$

But I've now come across the version $$ f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2!}f''(a)(x-a)^2+...$$

How can you show that the first version leads to the second?

Comment: Replace $x$ by $a$ and $h$ by $x-a$ in the first expression.

Comment: correct typo also in the first expansion. $hf'(x)$

Comment: Can you replace h with something that depends on a variable?